# Reduce yields ArcTan instead of Pi/4

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I expect this call:

```
Reduce[Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

to return

$x = \pi/4 + 2k\pi \ \vee \  x = -3/4 \ \pi + 2k\pi$.

However, $\pi/4$ and $3/4\ \pi$ get represented as `-2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]` and `-2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]]`.

MMA seems to know they're the same:

```
Reduce[-2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] == Pi/4]
```

returns `True`.

Note I have restricted the domain to $\mathbb{R}$. How can I force MMA to display the mathematical constants instead of the inverse tangent function?

Comment: `Reduce[Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0, x, Reals] // FullSimplify` gives a slightly restructured form. `Solve[Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0, x, Reals] // FullSimplify` is essentially the same. `Reduce` and `Solve` do not automatically simplify.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought of `FullSimplify` but I did try other options such as `ToRadicals`, which didn't have the effect. `Reduce[…]//FullSimplify//Solve[#, x] & // Expand` gives me the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Reduce[Sin[x] - Cos[x] == 0, x, Reals] /. 
 ArcTan[x__] :> FullSimplify@ArcTan[x]
```

$$c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left(x=-\frac{3 \pi }{4}+2 \pi  c_1\lor x=\frac{\pi }{4}+2 \pi  c_1\right)$$

Comment: Superb! What is the significance of the double underscore, can it be replaced with a single underscore? Is it there to differentiate the `x` in the equation from the `x` in the replacement rule?

Comment: A double underscore matches a sequence of one or more expressions. In this case, one can do without it.